# How to read files uploaded by spark-submit on Kubernetes

Tags: scala, apache-spark, kubernetes

I have Spark Jobs running on Yarn. These days I'm moving to Spark on Kubernetes.

On Kubernetes I'm having an issue: files uploaded via `--files` can't be read by Spark Driver.

On Yarn, as described in many answers I can read those files using `Source.fromFile(filename)`.

But I can't read files in Spark on Kubernetes.

- Spark version: 3.0.1
- Scala version: 2.12.6
- deploy-mode: cluster
- submit commands

  ```
  $ spark-submit --class <className> \
        --name=<jobName> \
        --master=k8s://https://api-hostname:6443 \
        ...
        --deploy-mode=cluster \
        --files app.conf \
        --conf spark.kubernetes.file.upload.path=hdfs://<nameservice>/path/to/sparkUploads/ \
        app.jar
  ```

After executing above command, `app.conf` is uploaded to `hdfs://<nameservice>/path/to/sparkUploads/spark-upload-xxxxxxx/`,

And in Driver's pod, I found `app.conf` in `/tmp/spark-******/` directory, `app.jar` as well.

But Driver can't read `app.conf`, `Source.fromFile(filename)` returns `null`, there was no permission problems.

#### Update 1

In Spark Web UI->"Environment" Tab, `spark://<pod-name>-svc.ni.svc:7078/files/app.conf` in "Classpath Entries" menu. Does this mean `app.conf` is available in classpath?

On the other hand, in Spark on Yarn `user.dir` property was included in System classpath.

---

I found [SPARK-31726: Make spark.files available in driver with cluster deploy mode on kubernetes](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-31726)

#### Update 2

I found that driver pod's `/opt/spark/work-dir/` dir was included in classpath.

but `/opt/spark/work-dir/` is empty on driver pod whereas on executor pod it contains `app.conf` and `app.jar`.

I think that is the problem and [SPARK-31726](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-31726) describes this.

#### Update 3

After reading Jacek's answer, I tested `org.apache.spark.SparkFiles.getRootDirectory()`.

It returns `/var/data/spark-357eb33e-1c17-4ad4-b1e8-6f878b1d8253/spark-e07d7e84-0fa7-410e-b0da-7219c412afa3/userFiles-59084588-f7f6-4ba2-a3a3-9997a780af24`

#### Update 4 - work around

- First, I make ConfigMaps to save files that I want to read driver/executors
- Next, The ConfigMaps are mounted on driver/executors. To mount ConfigMap, use [Pod Template](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-kubernetes.html#pod-template) or [Spark Operator](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spark-on-k8s-operator/blob/master/docs/user-guide.md#mounting-configmaps)

Comment: I faced same issue in spark 3.3.0
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-33782


Hope there are something new in next version

Answer (score 2):

`--files` files should be accessed using [SparkFiles.get](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/SparkFiles$.html#get(filename:String):String) utility:

> **get(filename: String): String**
>
> Get the absolute path of a file added through `SparkContext.addFile()`.

Answer (score 2):

I found the another temporary solution in spark 3.3.0

We can use flag `--archives`. The files without `tar`, `tar.gz`, `zip` are ignored unpacking step and after that they are placed on working dir of driver and executor.

Although the docs of `--archive` don't mention executor, I tested and it's working.

Answer (score 1):

With Spark 3.4,
spark.files, spark.jars, and spark.pyfiles all are placed in the current working directory of Driver & Executor while using K8s resource manager.

With 3.5 all these will be available on classpath as well.